# MySQL rotational ad system, stored procedure or php processing?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am writing a mysql/php ad system

I have an **ads** table with the following columns

**id, spot, city, state, img, url, views, clicks**

Each ad "spot" can have up to 6 rows for each "city/state" combo

Each page template has approximately 15 unique ad "spots"

On page load I need to grab the next ad in rotation for each of the "spots" in the template and increment their "views"

**What I have tried thus far...**

I figured to reduce database calls I would use a stored procedure, inserted below ("state" not yet implemented).

This procedure works by totaling views for all rows matching a given "spot" in a given "city/state" combo, dividing the total by the number of matching rows and using the remainder to determine the row to return.

I am wondering if this is the right approach. It's definitely not the fastest, and  "command out of sync" issues arise with other database functionality after I call it using mysqli, despite using "query" method.

I am wondering about alternatives.

If I do the processing in PHP and increment after the fact,  I assume I would need to ditch the "remainder " selection method and go with a less desired "random" selection method to avoid collision.

**Would it be wise to do the following**

1. Add a "page" column
2. Return all possible ads for the "page" within a "city/state" combo to PHP. ** Would be 6 times more than would be displayed.
3. Randomly select which ads to display via PHP
4. Update those selected rows via an UPDATE with a WHERE id IN () clause

**Any other suggestions?**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_ads //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_ads(in paramcity VARCHAR(30), IN paramspots VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE s VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE spots VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE p INT(10);
DECLARE l INT(10);

SET s = '';
SET spots = paramspots;
SET p = 0;
SET l = 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE output (id INT(10) NOT NULL, spot VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, url VARCHAR(255), image VARCHAR(255));

REPEAT

  SET p = LOCATE(',',spots);

  IF  p > 0 THEN
    SET s = SUBSTRING(spots,1,(p - 1));
    SET spots = SUBSTRING(spots, (p + 1));
    SET l = CHAR_LENGTH(spots);
  ELSE
    SET s = spots;
    SET spots = '';
    SET l = 0;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO output SELECT (@t2 := dt.id) AS id, spot, url, image FROM (
    SELECT @t1 := @t1 + 1 AS num, ads.*
    FROM ads, (SELECT @t1 := -1) init
    WHERE city = paramcity AND spot = s
    ORDER BY id ASC
  ) dt
  WHERE dt.num = (
  SELECT SUM(views) % COUNT(id) FROM ads
  WHERE city = paramcity AND spot = s);

UPDATE ads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = @t2;


UNTIL l <= 0 END REPEAT;

SELECT * FROM output;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE output;

END //
```

Comment: It looks like you might be able to do this without using the temp table, have you tried that? I think that could speed it up a bit, maybe not by too much but it'll add up with several sequential calls.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My need for the temp table arose out of needing a way to return the multiple selected rows to PHP. How else could I accomplish that.

Comment: Can you not use similar logic to what you use to get the rows to insert in order to return them to php? Also, I don't think you would lose performance by moving a lot of this logic to PHP and I think you'd certainly avoid the "command out of sync" issue as well as making it more extensible. The only part that you want to make sure you keep intact is the line that increments the views **SET views = views + 1**. Using the + operator in the SQL will ensure integrity during simultaneous transactions.